# How to startdrag() any of the objects in the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

I would like to start drag objects which is located in stage.There is movie clips in the stage which also encloses so many objects.when i click on any of the object it should be startdraged..Do u have any solution?

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, targetMC);
function targetMC(MouseEvent:Event):void
{
    var curinstance = MouseEvent.target.valueOf();
    curinstance.startDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer

```
package 
{

    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.text.GridFitType;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.*;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
    import fl.controls.DataGrid;
    import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {


        public function Main():void
        {
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            var mc_arr:Object = new Object();
            addChild(mc);
            for (var j:int=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                var clips:Array = [];


    var mcm:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mcm.graphics.drawRect(10*j,100,40,40);
    mcm.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    mcm.name = "mc" + j;
    addChild(mcm);



            }

        }

        public function onDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.startDrag();
        }
        public function onUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.stopDrag();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that's because you can't add a `startDrag` to a `SimpleButton`, you could do a conditional to either ignore SimpleButtons, or add it temporarily to a sprite and then drag the sprite.

Comment: you could also just not use SimpleButton, but an Extended movie Clip that does the essentially the same

Comment: how do i give conditional statement to avoid those simple buttons??

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the listener to the MC/Sprite or Root that holds the other resource

`root.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, targetMC);`

you can add a global var to see what object is being moved or iterate through all objects to stop them from draging on mouse up

or use hypeframework adjuster:

http://www.hypeframework.org/02_examples/adjuster/content/01_adjuster/

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer..........

```
package 
{

    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.text.GridFitType;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.*;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
    import fl.controls.DataGrid;
    import fl.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {


        public function Main():void
        {
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            var mc_arr:Object = new Object();
            addChild(mc);
            for (var j:int=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                var clips:Array = [];


    var mcm:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mcm.graphics.drawRect(10*j,100,40,40);
    mcm.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    mcm.name = "mc" + j;
    addChild(mcm);



            }

        }

        public function onDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.startDrag();
        }
        public function onUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.stopDrag();
        }
    }

}
```